# Id returned in one device is not matching with the other?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, angular, ionic2

I trying to get my friends on facebook using graph api. But My id is showing different in both desktop and my phone. I am working on Ionic 2, and I need to get my friends using android phone. By using the id generated by desktop I am getting some friends. But with the id generated by phone, the list of friends is empty. How to resolve this?

**here is my code**

```
fbGetDetails() {
    Facebook.getLoginStatus().then(response => {
        if(response.status == "connected"){
            Facebook.api("/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/friends", []).then(res => {
                alert("Total friends = " + res.summary.total_count);
                alert(response.authResponse.userID);
                if(res.data.length){
                    alert("Authorized friends = " + res.data.length);
                    for(var i=0; i<res.data.length; i++){
                        this.friends[i] = res.data[i];
                        // Facebook.api("/" + this.friends[i].id + "/picture", []).then(resp => {
                        //  this.friends[i].picture = resp.data.url;
                        // })
                    }
                } else{
                    alert("None of your frieds are using this app");
                }
            });
        }
    })
}
```

In the above code `authResponse.userID` will be the generated id. Actually, I was logged in desktop and checking in the graph api explorer. It is showing one of my friend. [image]

But even when I mention in the above code `"/me/friends"` instead of `"/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/friends"` also I am getting no friends in my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a different App for desktop and ionic. IDs are "App Scoped", so you get a different one per App. Also, you can only get friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission too.

Btw, you can just use `/me/friends` instead of `/user-id/friends`.